# Problema con metodo updateExistingPivot laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

He estado desarrollando en laravel 5.8 y pues ahora mismo estoy necesitando este método `updateExistingPivot` pero jamas, jamas me ha funcionado y pues ya se me dio por saber la razón y desearía que me ayudaran.

El error que me lanza es este:

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::updateExistingPivot()"

Aquí dejo el código por si estoy haciendo algo mal.

```
public function update(Request $request, Category $category, Article $article)
{
    $rules = [
      'name' => 'string',
      'quantity' => 'numeric'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $article = $category->articles()->updateExistingPivot($article, $request);

    return $this->showOne($article);// == response()->json($article)
}
```

Comment: Sería excelente si nos compartes ¿qué fallo o error ha resultado de usar dicho método?, ¿algún mensaje en pantalla?, ¿algún comportamiento inesperado?

Comment: @Aprendiz listo amigo

Comment: Estas tratando de usar este método en una relación de tipo `1:N` ? por que me parece que este método solo trabaja en relaciones de muchos a muchos, donde se involucra el uso de las relaciones `belongsToMany()`, pues tratas de actualizar el registro de una tabla pivote no?

Comment: ohhh con que era para relaciones ManyToMany? no lo sabia, entonces me tocara usar con el save, gracias

Comment: si, si ya me di cuenta es que pense estar en la seccion de HasMany jjaja. Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `upateExistingPivot` se refleja en la documentación para relaciones **Many to Many**:

Cuya función es:

> Actualizar filas de una tabla pivote

Teniendo la siguiente estructura, basándome en la [doc de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships):

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
```

Donde el primer argumento que acepta es: **la llave foránea de la tabla pivote**
Y el segundo argumento es: **un arreglo de atributos para ser actualizados**