# Laravel - Relación muchos a muchos con información adicional en la tabla re la relación

Tags: laravel, formularios, modelorelacional

El problema que tengo es que quiero Crear, Actualizar y Eliminar "Contactos" que pertenecen a "Instituciones" y tienen una informacion "Adicional" en la relacion "Contacto-Institucion", pero no quiero hacer un ABM de "Contacto" y un ABM de "Informacion Adicional".

¿Como podria modelarlo y programar el formulario para persistir los datos?

Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: Revisa lo que respondo aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285001/problema-con-metodo-updateexistingpivot-laravel/285005?r=SearchResults#285005

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar lo que explica la documentacion

Updating A Record On A Pivot Table
If you need to update an existing row in your pivot table, you may use **updateExistingPivot** method. This method accepts the pivot record foreign key and an array of attributes to update:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships